# QuantumDB Plugin - Getting past errors in Aptana 3.0.6

Tags: database, database-design, data-binding, aptana3

Has anyone been successful in installing the QuantumDB database plugin to the stand-alone Aptana Studio 3.0.6?  I've tried since 3.0 to get this installed so I could avoid having to layout the money for expensive IDEs like Zend or Dreamweaver, but they all have database viewing and developer tools that are quite nice.  I was told that QuantumDB was what I needed, but everytime I try to install I get "depenedency errors" and the advice I get is "use a different IDE because it's near impossible to get it working in Aptana. If you have this working and know the steps to getting it installed, please post.

Answer (score 3):

I installed without problems in such sequence:

`Help` -> `Install New Software…` -> `Add` -> `Location:`
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/

selecting these three packages in the list:

- Graphical Editing Framework Draw2d
- Graphical Editing Framework GEF
- Graphical Editing Framework Zest Visualization Toolkit

-> `Next >`

Then installed Quantum DB plugin in same way from

http://quantum.sourceforge.net/update-site/

selecting all packages in the list…

Comment: Thanks... I had to download the MySQL driver from their site and configure that before it would work, but now its fine.

Comment: This process will not work in later versions of Aptana. It seems that the Appcelerator folks refuse to package the foundations packages that are needed.

Comment: @K.Kathman I just installed by this way quantum db on aptana 3.3.1 so it works on later versions.